# New recaptcha not filling in g-recaptcha-response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, recaptcha

I have a registration page that requires the user to fill in a noCaptcha reCaptcha, but the widget is not filling in the `g-recaptcha-response` field. When I submit the form, my Node app is using a script I wrote to submit the response to Google and verify that the captcha is valid. That part is correct, but the recaptcha widget just won't fill out the response textarea it adds to the page. However, the jQuery I wrote that checks the value of the response field lets the page go through if the captcha is checked, but not if it is unchecked like it is supposed to, but the field is still not filled out.

**What I need:** *To find out why reCaptcha isn't filling out the field when I POST the form to my backend.*

Below is my register page's code and the jQuery running the page:

```
<div id="registerCard" class="login-card">
  <p class="profile-name-card">Narrify Account Registration</p><br>
  <form id="registerForm" action="/register" method="post" role="form" data-toggle="validator" class="form-signin has-validation-callback">
    <input type="text" name="firstName" required="" placeholder="First name" autofocus="" class="form-control">
    <input type="text" name="lastName" required="" placeholder="Last name" class="form-control">
    <input id="inputRegistrationEmail" type="email" name="email" required="" data-validation="email" placeholder="Email address" class="form-control">
    <input type="email" required="" data-validation="confirmation" data-validation-confirm="email" placeholder="Email repeat" class="form-control">
    <input id="inputRegistrationPassword" type="password" name="password" required="" data-validation="strength" data-validation-strength="2" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
    <input type="password" required="" data-validation="confirmation" data-validation-confirm="password" placeholder="Password repeat" class="form-control">
    <div data-sitekey="[MYSITEKEY]" class="g-recaptcha"></div><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-lg btn-signin">Register</button>
  </form>
  <a id="login-link" href="#" onclick="showLoginForm()" class="forgot-password">Login</a>
</div>
```

The jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  // Switch to either load an avatar from autocomplete or remove the loading bar
  if($("#inputEmail").val() != "") {
    updateAvatar();
  } else {
    $("#image-progress").fadeOut();
  }
  // Event Handlers for links and inputs
  $("#inputEmail").change(updateAvatar);

  var url = window.location.pathname;

  if(url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("#") + 1) == "register")
    showRegisterForm();

  $.validate({ modules: "security" });

  $("#registerForm").submit(function(e) {
    var recaptcha = $("#g-recaptcha-response").val();
    if(recaptcha == "") {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("Please complete the captcha");
    }
  });
});

function updateAvatar() {
  // Show the loading bar until it is removed by a new image loading
  $("#image-progress").fadeIn();
  // Set the avatar image based on the input of the Email field
  $("#profile-avatar").attr("src", "https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/" + md5($("#inputEmail").val().toLowerCase()) + "?d=identicon&r=pg");
  // Set event handler to hide loading bar once the image loads
  $("#profile-avatar").on("load", function() {
    $("#image-progress").fadeOut();
  });
}

function showResetForm() {
  alert("test");
}

function showRegisterForm() {
  $("#loginCard").fadeOut();
  $("#registerCard").fadeIn();
}

function showLoginForm() {
  $("#registerCard").fadeOut();
  $("#loginCard").fadeIn();
}
```